# How to check if two keys in dictionary hold the same value

Tags: python, dictionary

This seems like such an obvious thing that I feel like I'm missing out on something, but how do you find out if two different keys in the same dictionary have the exact same value? For example, if you have the dictionary `test` with the keys `a`, `b`, and `c` and the keys `a` and `b` both have the value of 10, how would you figure that out? (For the point of the question, please assume a large number of keys, say 100, and you have no knowledge of how many duplicates there are, if there are multiple sets of duplicates, or if there are duplicates at all). Thanks.

Comment: There shouldn't be any duplicate keys in a dict...  Unless you meant, ones that are the same between the two separate dicts.

Comment: the keys wouldn't be duplicate, but different keys may have the same values. I'm trying to understand how to figure out which keys have the same valuues

Comment: I think he means duplicate values for different keys.  At least that is what the example implies.

Answer (score 9):

```
len(dictionary.values()) == len(set(dictionary.values()))
```

This is under the assumption that the only thing you want to know is if there are any duplicate values, not which values are duplicates, which is what I assumed from your question. Let me know if I misinterpreted the question.

Basically this is just checking if any entries were removed when the values of the dictionary were casted to an object that by definition doesn't have any duplicates.

If the above doesn't work for your purposes, this should be a better solution:

```
set(k for k,v in d.items() if d.values().count(v) > 1))
```

Basically the second version just checks to see if there is more than one entry that will be removed if you try popping it out of the list.

Comment: @hivert Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't equality already ambiguous for objects that aren't hashable?

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear. I wanted to know which values were duplicates

Comment: Not at all. Equality of lists is perfectly defined whereas hashing of lists is not allowed because of mutability.

Comment: @Kpower which values or which keys?

Comment: @SlaterTyranus keys, sorry

Comment: @hivert conditional tuple casting?

Comment: @Slater this only will work for lists, and not eg if values are for example dicts.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: I know this is an old question but when I run your second solution "set ....", I get a TypeError: an integer is required. Why? I googled it, can't find something to answer my question. thanks

Comment: @HR123r Whoops! Looks like there's a typo. Updated.

Answer (score 7):

To detect all of these cases:

```
>>> import collections
>>> d = {"a": 10, "b": 15, "c": 10}
>>> value_to_key = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in d.iteritems():
...     value_to_key[v].append(k)
...
>>> value_to_key
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {10: ['a', 'c'], 15: ['b']})
```

@hivert makes the excellent point that this only works if the values are hashable.  If this is not the case, there is no nice O(n) solution(sadly).  This is the best I can come up with:

```
d = {"a": [10, 15], "b": [10, 20], "c": [10, 15]}
values = []
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    must_insert = True
    for val in values:
        if val[0] == v:
            val[1].append(k)
            must_insert = False
            break
    if must_insert: values.append([v, [k]])

print [v for v in values if len(v[1]) > 1] #prints [[[10, 15], ['a', 'c']]]
```

Comment: @Ben good point, assuming that I've understood what Kpower is trying to detect, I've edited in a solution that should solve the problem.

Comment: This also only works if values are hashable. Think for example of what happens if value are lists.

Comment: @hivert yes I noticed this from your other comments.  There is no nice(O(n)) solution to the problem if the values aren't hashable, as far as I can tell.

Comment: The downvote (not me) was probably because your first version (of three) was not about the question at all. "Stealth" edits do get seen if I load the page between your initial submission and your first edit if they are closely separated in time, as happened for me. SO shouldn't be a footrace for "frist!!!!".

Comment: @msw I suppose that makes sense.  When I posted there hadn't been enough clarification in the comments for me to realize that my answer was not what Kpower was asking.

Comment: Fair 'nuff, I say with bonhomie as "Fair 'nuff" isn't long enough.

Comment: @NolenRoyalty You are right. If you can only compare two values then checking that there is no duplicate needs at least O(n^2) comparisons.

Comment: @hivert I've added a super ugly solution to deal with the case of non-hashable values.

Answer (score 5):

You can tell *which* are the duplicate values by means of a reverse index - where the key is the duplicate value and the value is the set of keys that have that value (this will work as long as the values in the input dictionary are hashable):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = {'w':20, 'x':10, 'y':20, 'z':30, 'a':10}
dd = defaultdict(set)

for k, v in d.items():
    dd[v].add(k)

dd = { k : v for k, v in dd.items() if len(v) > 1 }

dd
=> {10: set(['a', 'x']), 20: set(['y', 'w'])}
```

From that last result it's easy to obtain the set of keys with duplicate values:

```
set.union(*dd.values())
=> set(['y', 'x', 'a', 'w'])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
dico = {'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':1}
result = {}
for val in dico:
    if dico[val] in result:
        result[dico[val]].append(val)
    else:
        result[dico[val]] = [val]
>>> result
{0: ['a', 'b'], 1: ['c']}
```

Then you can filter on the result's key that has a value (list) with more than one element, e.g. a duplicate has been found

Comment: @Ketouem is result just {} at the start?

Comment: Yes indeed, my bad, I'll change my snippet

Comment: You could also use `result = defaultdict(list)` (defaultdict imported from `collections`) and then just `for val in dico: result[dico[val]].append(val)`

Comment: Indeed, but I wanted to answer this question without resorting to an external module (I can be quite narrow minded sometimes ^^)

Answer (score 1):

Build another dict mapping the values of the first dict to all keys that hold that value:

```
import collections

inverse_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for key in original_dict:
    inverse_dict[original_dict[key]].append(key)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
keys = set()
for key1 in d:
    for key2 in d:
        if key1 == key2: continue
        if d[key1] == d[key2]:
            keys |= {key1, key2}
```

i.e. that's Θ(n²) what you want. The reason is that a dict does not provide Θ(1) search of a key, given a value. So better rethink your data structure choices if that's not good enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list in conjunction with dictionary to find duplicate elements!
Here is a simple code demonstrating the same:

```
d={"val1":4,"val2":4,"val3":5,"val4":3}
l=[]
for key in d:
      l.append(d[key])
      l.sort()
print(l)
for i in range(len(l)):
    if l[i]==l[i+1]:
        print("true, there are duplicate elements.")
        print("the keys having duplicate elements are: ")
        for key in d:
            if d[key]==l[i]:
                print(key)
        break
```

output:

runfile('C:/Users/Andromeda/listeqtest.py', wdir='C:/Users/Andromeda')

```
[3, 4, 4, 5]
true, there are duplicate elements.
the keys having duplicate elements are: 
val1
val2
```

when you sort the elements in the list, you will find that equal values always appear together!